# Randomly calling functions to execute

Tags: python, random, python-2.x

I have made this short questionnaire:

```
from random import randint

def pancakes():
    q = raw_input("Do you like pancakes?")
    if q == "yes":
        print("Great!")
    elif q == "no":
        print("Hmmm...")

def french_toast():
    q = raw_input("Do you like french toast?")
    if q == "yes":
        print("Oh!")
    elif q == "no":
        print("Same here!")

def random():
    num = 2
    while num > 0:
        random = randint(1, 2)
        if random == 1:
            num = num -1
            pancakes()
         elif random == 2:
             num = num -1
             french_toast()

random()
```

My goal here was to get the questions in a random order. But sometimes the same question will be asked twice since it's randomly chosen.

So how can I make it ask the same question only once?

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to give your variables the same name as a standard module, especially one that your script is using. It won't hurt anything in this script, but it is a bit confusing for anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a `while` loop, I'd suggest you use a `for` loop in conjunction with `random.sample`. Create a list of functions before-hand to provide to `sample`:

```
from random import sample

funcs = [french_toast, pancakes]
for func in sample(funcs, len(funcs)):
    func()
```

this will now loop through all functions randomly selecting a function in each iteration.

Alternatively, you could `shuffle` the list (performs in-place) with `random.shuffle` and then iterate through it, that will be faster too (though, speed shouldn't be the biggest concern here):

```
from random import shuffle

funcs = [french_toast, pancakes]
shuffle(funcs)
for func in funcs:
    func()
```

Put these in a function if so required:

```
from random import shuffle

# use *funcs for passing arbitrary number of 
# functions as positional arguments.
def call_funcs_randomly(funcs):
    shuffle(funcs)
    for func in funcs:
        func()
```

and call them:

```
call_funcs_randomly([french_toast, pancakes])
```

---

As a comment noted, don't use `random` as a function name, it has the possibility of masking the module `random` leading to odd looking errors.

Comment: you are really suggesting the same things like me simultaneously. its really funny :-)

Comment: Even though it shouldn't be the biggest concern, it is now resolved by your answer :)

Comment: yes it is, but I found it funny, how two different people think about the same things simultaneously...

Comment: @BloodyD I've seen this happen *many* times; especially when an answer is somewhat obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I would use  `random.sample` [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample). Just create a list of indices to your questions and sample 2 of them.

EDIT:

additionally, you could use `random.shuffle` [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
random.shuffle(questions)
for question in questions:
    # process your random question once
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this for your last question (`random` is not a good name! you might overwrite the module of the same name [although you are fine the way do do it right now])

```
def random_questions():
    eligible_questions = [pancakes, french_toast]
    while eligible_questions:
        question = random.choice(eligible_questions)
        eligible_questions.remove(question)
        question()
```

put the questions in a list, select one with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice), remove it from the list and execute it. stop if the question list is empty. this way every question is selected exactly once.

this is easily extended if you want to add more questions.

on second thought: the `shuffle` version in [Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543503/4954037) is a lot cleaner!